# Getting error "Cannot find 'previewWeather' in scope"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a beginner developer and I am getting this error "Cannot find 'previewWeather' in scope" when I have the "previewWeather" variable in my "Model Data" file?

struct WeatherView: View {
var weather: ResponseBody

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text(weather.name)
                    .bold().font(.title)
                
                Text("Today,\(Date().formatted(.dateTime.month() .day().hour().minute()))")
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 40))
                        
                        Text(weather.weather[0].main)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    
                    Text(weather.main.feels_like.roundDouble() + "°")
                        .font(.system(size: 100))
                        .fontWeight((.bold))
                        .padding()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 80)
                
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/24/21/33/city-4791269_960_720.png")) { image in image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 350)
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                Text("Weather now")
                    .bold().padding(.bottom)
                
                HStack {
                    WeatherRow(logo: "thermometer", name: "Min temp", value: (weather.main.temp_min.roundDouble() + "°"))
                    Spacer()
                    WeatherRow(logo: "thermometer", name: "Max temp", value: (weather.main.temp_max.roundDouble() + "°"))
                }
                
                HStack {
                    WeatherRow(logo: "wind", name: "Wind speed", value: (weather.wind.speed.roundDouble() + "m/s"))
                    Spacer()
                    WeatherRow(logo: "humidity", name: "Humidity", value: (weather.main.humidity.roundDouble() + "%"))
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding()
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.685, saturation: 0.988, brightness: 0.377))
            .background(.white)
            .cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
        }
        
        
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    .background(Color(hue: 0.685, saturation: 0.988, brightness: 0.377))
    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
}
```

}

struct WeatherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
WeatherView(weather: previewWeather) < -Error is here[image: Screenshot of my code]
}
}

import Foundation

// previewWeather var here -> var previewWeather: ResponseBody = load("weatherData.json").

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
let data: Data

```
guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
}

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix your error:

```
struct Weather_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previewWeather = previewWeather() // <- your "Model Data" 
   
    static var previews: some View {
        WeatherView(weather: previewWeather)
    }

}
```